# SocketTimeoutException thrown

Tags: java, networking, timeout

'java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out'
I'm gettting this error after looping after a while.
Why am I getting a SocketTimeoutException? And how could I fix this error?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            URLConnection connection = getURLConnection("http://www.trekpv.com");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String s;
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            reader.close();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private URLConnection getURLConnection(String s) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(s);
    URLConnection urlconnection = url.openConnection();
    urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    urlconnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlconnection.addRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    urlconnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120716 Firefox/15.0a2");
    urlconnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    urlconnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    urlconnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    return urlconnection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Connect timed out' means there was no response at all. Probably there is a firewall in the way.

Answer (score 1):

SocketTimeoutException occurs when the url specified is not fetched in a certain time duration. this may occur due to slow internet connection, or there is some fault in code which makes it unable for `getURLConnection("http://www.trekpv.com")`funtion to fetch the url.